# onehot encoding: preserve column structure

Tags: r, one-hot-encoding

Im trying to solve a problem that has arisen with the productionisation of an XGBoost model. My current problem is the column order in the training data is not replicated identically in the column order in the production data I need to score. The issue has arisen from the onehot encoding step. Where not all levels of each variable are present in the production scoring data that was in the training data. This causes the scoring to come out with inconsistent and incorrect results, or the scoring process fails completely.

In an attempt to overcome I am trying to come up with a process inside the onehot encoding step that will ensure the column structure is consistent. My theory is that if I save the header vector created from the training dataset, I could then call the onehot predict function on this header set for each production scoring set.

For example. If I have 2 datasets test and train. I can onehot encode the train data through the onehot package as:

```
header <- onehot(train, max_levels = 100)

trainmatrix <- predict(header, train)
```

To preserve the column structure of this matrix, I want to simply use the header object already created above to onehot encode the test data, simply:

```
testmatrix <- predict(header, test)
```

Issue is that the results do not line up as I had hoped.

If I have train data:

[image: train data]

To create header vector:

[image: header vector]

Then use this to onehot encode test data:

[image: test data]

I get matrix:

[image: sparse matrix]

These results obviously do not meet my expectations for an effective solution. Does anyone have a different solution for this?

Comment: Welcome to SO Stephen. I recommend editing your question to include the data, vector and matrix as text in the question. At the least you should embed the images in your question instead of as links. These measures make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: I tried embedding the images, but as I'm a new user it won't allow me to embed images unless I get like 10 honesty points or something. I'll take your suggestion to include it as text. Thanks James

Comment: Roger that, I forgot about the rules for low reputation users. They are annoying but help prevent spammers from wrecking the place. Good luck with your question.